# Find difference in fix length file unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to create a shell script/command which does below:

I have a fixed length file with following format

```
   Column No.    Column Name
   --------------------------
    1-4          Name
    5-8          Number 1
    8-12         Number 2
    12-34        Number 3
    35-45        Some other garbage not of my use
```

Now I want to find difference of `Number 1` and `Number 2` and place the result at location of `Number 1`. The file is fixed length so exact my difference result should be placed at location 5-8.

I tried using `awk` but not exactly getting how can this be done.

Comment: They represent  column no. Please refer now

Comment: Its bit unclear. Please post some sampel inputs and outputs

Comment: reveal real data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk` you can set a parameter named `FIELDWITHS` like this:

```
cat file
one  number data
two  number more info
threedata   house
```

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 7 10" '{print $1,$2,$3}' OFS="-*-" file
one  -*-number -*-data
two  -*-number -*-more info
three-*-data   -*-house
```

So for your data:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="4 4 4 22 10" '{print "NAME=" $1}' file
```